# How do draw radialgradients swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cgcontext, radial-gradients

I am making a metaball implementation in swift and have ran into some problems. Currently I am not able to make a radial gradient draw to the screen this is my current attempt to make a radial gradient.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    var colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var colors : [CGColor] = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor]
    var locations :[CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 ]
    var gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, colors, locations)

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), CGFloat(20), CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), CGFloat(30), CGGradientDrawingOptions(kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation))
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting any compiler or runtime errors? Does the app run? What's the specific issue?

Comment: @jkaufman well it runs fine but it doesnt display anything, the screen is just gray

Comment: I do get this error but it doesnt seem to fatal or anything "CGContextDrawRadialGradient: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update." And i feel like I got the context correctly